# How to customize Number of posts on front page in drupal 8

Tags: 8

I went to URL:

```
admin/config/system/site-information
```

I can't find **Number of posts on front page** settings available there like Drupal 7 has.

I am using drupal 8 version : `8.0.0-dev`

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the front page is a view now, you can find its settings under `/admin/structure/views/view/frontpage`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which view to edit.

Comment: admin/structure/views/view/frontpage this one it is.